# How to structure a more complex API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that accepts a simple comma separated string of data from a piece of telemetry hardware out in the field. It then needs to carry out processing to establish whether or not to carry out various actions, and then to carry those actions out. These are things like storing the data in a database or triggering email alerts. The API simply needs to respond to say that the data has been received, and then all the work can happen on the server, while the API continues to accept other requests. There are many thousands of requests from many thousands of pieces of hardware every few seconds.

As I am new to ASP.NET MVC I am not sure of the best way to carry this out. I'd like the api controller to do some basic checks, and then reply with a success response (currently a message saying "Processed"). It needs to send data off to other processes to do the work in the background. The hardware that makes the post isnt interested in the sucess of the subsequent work as it needs to drop the connection quickly until it next reports. As there are so many pieces of hardware reporting, the live connections need to complete and close as quickly as possible.

Should these additional functions be Asynch functions in separate classes? If so should these be void to that they can carry on in the background while the http request has finished i.e. no need to await them? The API controller is becoming quite bloated with code as there are so many possible sub routines to carry out.

```
   public class MyApiController : ApiController
    {
        public class RecievedPost
        {
            public string Data { get; set; }
        }

        private BaseContext db = new BaseContext();

        public HttpResponseMessage PostResponse([FromBody] RecievedPost recievedPost)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] dataArray = recievedPost.Data.Split(',');
                //run various checks and trigger various other processes based on the results.
                }
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Processed")
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("API Error - " + ex.ToString())
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: The controller action itself should probably be `async`, but overall it sounds like none of the alluded-to logic should be in the controller or really in this application at all.  It sounds like the WebAPI should do nothing more than persist the data.  Perhaps to a database or to a message queue.  Then some other application, maybe a Windows Service or something of that nature, should read from the stored data and perform the rest of the processing.  The question as-is is a bit broad, but at a high level that sounds like the architecture you're describing.

Comment: To add on to @David 's comment. You could also have Services inside your web api project that also have the logic (the brains or business logic of the request) within them. Then based on that you can pass back what to do. Also it sounds like you are using a complex URI to pass parameters to your web api. Take a look at this [tutorial](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) on passing json as a parameter on your request. I think it will be easier to process data in a json format instead of a comma separated format.